# GitVersion, hotfix and pull requests

Tags: azure-devops, gitversion

I have a setup in Azure DevOps and are trying to configure GitVersion to do our versioning. Works fine except for pull requests of hotfixes

example:
build of hotfix branch gives me version 1.2.3-beta...
pull request of that hotfix branch starts gives med 1.3.0-PullRequest

I expected it to be 1.2.3-PullRequest.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Hi @user3164608, How are things going? Is the method (GitVersion.yml) you found can help you solve the problem? If it works, could please post an answer to share the details of this method. This may help more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Thanks. Of course, if my suggestion is better, you can mark it.

Comment: Not sure if there is a problem in the GitVersion.yml file or in git version task. Seems like if I build the hotfix branch before making the Pull request, which triggers a build, the version number is as expected. But if the hotfix branch is only build as part of PR, the is counts up the minor part as if it feature or release. But I still need to conduct some testing to confirm this, just havn't had the time yet.

Comment: Thanks for you replay, @user3164608. If you have any progress, feel free to tell me. And if possible, could you please share the details of your build pipeline definition? So that we can check more detailed configurations to analyze and provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

How do you set the build number in the build pipeline definition for Pull Request?

According to your comments, you want the build for PR has the same build number with the latest build for the **`hotfix`** branch, except the suffix, right?

If so, you can try set up and run a shell script (**PowerShell** as example here) like as below in the build pipeline for PR.

```sh
# Convernt PAT to Base64 string
$pat = "personal access token"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

# Set up headers
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionID}&branchName=$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)&`$top=1&api-version=6.1-preview.6"

# Run the API and return the response body
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method GET

# Get buildNumber of the latest build for hotfix branch
$buildNumber_hotfix = $response.value[0].buildNumber
Write-Host "$buildNumber_hotfix"

# Replace the suffix
$buildNumber_PR = $buildNumber_hotfix.replace("beta","PullRequest")
Write-Host "$buildNumber_PR"

# Update the buildNumber of current build for the PR
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildNumber_PR"
```

**Description:**

1. Parameters in the REST API "[**Builds - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)".

   - The '**`definitionID`**' is the ID of the build pipeline for hotfix branch.
   - The '**`branchName`**' is the source branch of the PR (e.g. **`refs/heads/hotfix`**), you can directly use the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) '**`$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)`**' to get the branch name.
   - Set the value of '**`$top`**' as **`1`**. This will let the API call only return the latest build.
2. [**Logging commands - UpdateBuildNumber**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number)

Comment: Haven't tried. Found an older GitVersion.yml file, and now it seems to work as expected (most of the time) I have saw one glitch yesterday. I'll keep testing and see if I can figure it out. Otherwise I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the default gitversion configuration that you can configure using `gitversion init`.

Each PR increments the `patch` version - `1.1.1`. So each PR is considered a hotfix. What you need to do then is you need to add commit message `+semver:minor` to bump the `minor` version - `1.2.0`. If you would like to leave it as a hotfix do not include the commit message.

Then you promote the build from `main` to your live environment and tag your `main` branch with `1.2.0` manually or automatically.

This is assuming you are using the default `ContinuousDelivery` mode.